# What is the correct way to set state from another hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I have a query parameter like this:

```
const router = useRouter()
const { name } = router.query
```

I want to use this `name` and pass it to a value that has state:

```
const [queryName, setQueryName] = useState('')
```

The issue is I cannot pass it as the default, like this: `useState(name)` because the `name` updates.

So rather than using the `name` as the default value I'd have to set it.

```
setQueryName(name)
```

This however is also not valid, I can't just set it within the component like this.

So I'd have to use `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
    setQueryName(name)
}, [name])
```

However this is triggering a infinite error:

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.

What is the correct way to set state from another hook?

Comment: Why not directly use `name` from `router.query`?

Comment: I agree with Ramesh. It's generally considered anti-pattern to store derived state in local component state. What's the point/purpose of saving the `name` into state when you could/should just reference `router.query.name` in the component instead?

Comment: Let's say I'm taking a URI parameter and then using that value to populate a form field, and the form field is edible, you'd want to do exactly what I am doing. What I'm trying to do is not that radical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is the best way to do something like this.

Next.js router query params can be a `string | string[]`, so I wrapped the value in a memo wrapped `useQueryParam`.

```
const useQueryParam = (value) => {
    return useMemo(() => (Array.isArray(value) ? value[0] : value) || '', [value])
}
const router = useRouter()
const queryName = useQueryParam(router.query.name)
const [name, setName] = useState('')
useEffect(() => setName(queryName), [queryName])
```

Comment: Have you tried `const name = router.query.name`? What does state have to do with it? You haven't shown us the usage but it seems like a prop like any other prop.

Answer (score -2):

There is a little trick you could do.

And I imagine it would make the code more readable. The value you receive from url is used as initial value and it can be changed later by some UI in the page, right?

```
const router = useRouter();
const { name: initialName } = router.query; // get name, but we'll be calling it "initialName" onward.

const [name, setName] = useState(initialName);
```

Comment: The router value updates and fires multiple times, starts as null, and then has value. I believe that this will only capture the the first value and apply that as the default.